# How to implement Error Boundary with React Hooks Component

Tags: reactjs

How can we implement error Boundary in React Hooks. Is it even supported with react Hooks?

Answer (score 46):

The questions is whether it is possible to implement Error Boundary as a hook and the answer is no BUT it does not mean that you can not use Error Boundary class components in a project which you use hooks heavily.

Create a Error Boundary class component and wrap your React Functional Components(hooks) with the Error Boundary class component.

Comment: This advice is perfect. Saw the same happening on a big production example and will implement the same in my project as well.

Comment: This throws a `Renedered fewer hooks than expected` error for me, because the hooks are behind a conditional statement.

Comment: For those of us who love the functional programming of React and Hooks, this option makes us sad ["It must be a class component "](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/use-react-error-boundary-to-handle-errors-in-react#react-error-boundary).

Answer (score 27):

You can implement error boundary in react hooks with the help of `react-error-boundary` package.

`npm install --save react-error-boundary`

Then:

```js
import {ErrorBoundary} from 'react-error-boundary'

function ErrorFallback({error, resetErrorBoundary}) {
  return (
    <div role="alert">
      <p>Something went wrong:</p>
      <pre>{error.message}</pre>
      <button onClick={resetErrorBoundary}>Try again</button>
    </div>
  )
}

const ui = (
  <ErrorBoundary
    FallbackComponent={ErrorFallback}
    onReset={() => {
      // reset the state of your app so the error doesn't happen again
    }}
  >
    <ComponentThatMayError />
  </ErrorBoundary>
)
```

Please read more on [React-error-boundary](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-error-boundary)

Comment: Note that this react-error-boundary looks like as good as you're gonna get until they officially support it in react. This library is written by [Brian Vaughn](https://github.com/bvaughn) who worked on React Dev Tools at Facebook. There's also a nice blog post from Kent Dodds about [Use react-error-boundary to handle errors in React](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/use-react-error-boundary-to-handle-errors-in-react)

Answer (score 18):

***There is no Error Boundaries in hook yet ***

```
componentDidCatch 
and 
getDerivedStateFromError
```

There are no Hook equivalents for these methods yet, but they will be added soon.

Comment: That's what it was said when hooks were released in 2018; it's almost 2022 and no sign of this getting fixed.

Comment: Today is in 2022.

Comment: There is not any official hook for that , its been 2023. but you can simply use try...catch to catch component errors like this:

Answer (score 11):

I wrote [react-use-error-boundary](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-use-error-boundary) to achieve this.

React 16 introduced [Error Boundaries](https://reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html). As of React 17, there still is [not an equivalent hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#do-hooks-cover-all-use-cases-for-classes) for function components.

I liked the API implemented by Preact's [useErrorBoundary](https://preactjs.com/guide/v10/hooks/#useerrorboundary) and attempted to recreate a similar API. If you're interested in building this from scratch you can [checkout the code on GitHub](https://github.com/tatethurston/react-use-error-boundary).

Answer (score 9):

You can't do that with hooks. Hooks do not have an equivalent of componentDidCatch. See [this section of the hook FAQ](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#do-hooks-cover-all-use-cases-for-classes)

> - `getSnapshotBeforeUpdate`, `componentDidCatch` and `getDerivedStateFromError`: There are no Hook equivalents for these methods yet, but they will be added soon.

Comment: This is useful purely because you mention the exact part of the FAQ that is missing `componentDidCatch`. In the FAQ they don't refer to 'Error Boundaries', all other answers here are assuming you know Error Boundaries means componentDidCatch.

Answer (score -1):

how about this:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

function ErrorBoundary(props) {
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    // Catch errors thrown by child components
    const handleErrors = (err) => {
      setError(err);
    };
    window.addEventListener('error', handleErrors);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('error', handleErrors);
    };
  }, []);
  
  if (error) {
    return <h1>Something went wrong: {error.message}</h1>;
  }
  
  return props.children;
}

export default ErrorBoundary;
```

Comment: This falls short of a typical ErrorBoundry's ability to catch errors locally. Consider the potential need of many ErrroBoundry locations - this pattern you suggest would not be compatible. In my opinion this solution is an anti pattern when we have the class implementation available to us.

Comment: `window.addEventListener('error', ...)` doesn't catch uncaught errors, read about what it's actually for https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/error_event.